# MongoDB nested document update neither throws error nor updates document using python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I am trying to update a document in the below MongoDB collection. It neither throws an error nor updates the document.

Here is my collection:

```
customer_docs = [
  {
    "customerName": "Yeshua Galisanao",
    "msgId": "100",
    "productDetails": [
      {
        "productName": "prod1",
        "prodSerialNum": "sdgha53643657354"
      },
      {
        "productName": "prod2",
        "prodSerialNum": "fafruirykjnjhgukg"
      }
    ],
    "customer-address": [
      {
        "primaryAddress": [
          {
            "street": "#43 Easy Street",
            "city": "Niceton",
            "state": "PH",
            "zip": "57733"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "secondaryAddress": [
          {
            "street": "23",
            "city": "seattle"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "customerName": "Karl Mike",
    "msgId": "101",
    "productDetails": [
      {
        "productName": "prod10",
        "prodSerialNum": "764hreopirrrhfnsf"
      },
      {
        "productName": "prod11",
        "prodSerialNum": "fsdfhsfybdfmdsgfyuu"
      }
    ],
    "customer-address": [
      {
        "primaryAddress": [
          {
            "street": "#66 Easy Street",
            "zip": "57733"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is the python code which tries to update serial number for the customer "Karl Mike" to "newSerailNumber":

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")
db = client.MyDb
customer_col = db.customer

my_query1 = {"customerName": "Karl Mike"}
for customer in customer_col.find(my_query1):
    for prod in customer["productDetails"]:
        if prod["productName"] == "prod1" and prod["prodSerialNum"] != "abcdefghijklmop":
            my_query2 = {
                "customer": "Karl Mike",
                "productDetails.productName": "prod1"
            }
            customer_col.update_one(my_query2, {"$set": {"productDetails.0.prodSerialNum": "newSerailNumber"}})
            print("oops reached")
```

But the document update is not happening here. What I am doing wrong? Why the failure of document update does not throw any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my bad! First of all there is a typo in my code. Instead of using `"customerName"`  in `my_query2`, I used `"customer"` as key.

The below code just works fine:

```
my_query1 = {"customerName": message["customer_name"]}
for customer in customer_col.find(my_query1):
    for prod in customer["productDetails"]:
        if message["prod"] == prod["productName"] and message["serial_number"] != prod["prodSerialNum"]:
            my_query2 = {
                "customerName": "Karl Mike",
                "productDetails.productName": "prod1",
                "productDetails.prodSerialNum": prod["prodSerialNum"]
            }
            customer_col.update_many(my_query2, {"$set": {"productDetails.$.prodSerialNum": "newSerailNumber"}})
            print("oops reached")
```

But still wondering - why there was no error thrown for the same.